# how to find high beta stocks

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-markets, beta

I'm looking for high beta stocks ( >= 3 ) and could find only a small handful.
I've been googling "list of beta" etc. but get very few.

Maybe there just aren't that many >= 3.

Comment: Your brokerage should have a good way to screen by greeks, which are you using?

Comment: Vanguard and E-trade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yahoo Finance's Equity Screener](https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/new) lets you screen stocks on their S&P 500 betas -- both 1-year betas and 3-year monthly-return betas. That way you can restrict yourself to looking at stocks whose beta is not just briefly high but has been for a longer period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Finviz.com

From the menu select:

SCREENER

CUSTOM

Choose the filters that you desire such as BETA

When BETA appears as a header in the data fields, click on it to sort in ascending or descending order.

Here's the straight to that page [LINK](https://www.finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152&o=-beta).

It shows 123 stocks with a beta of > 3.00